# Display svg icon in data.map, does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to map my data to create map markers:

```
import ShellIcon from '../../../assets/images/xxx.svg';
import BPIcon from '../../../assets/images/xxx.svg';
import TexacoIcon from '../../../assets/images/xx.svg';

    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            ...
    
            <MapView
              ..>
              {staticData.map((marker, i) => {
                const MarkerIcon = marker.type;
    
                return (
                  <Marker key={index} coordinate={item.coordinates} ref={markerRef}>
                    <MapPin price={item.price} icon={MarkerIcon} />
                  </Marker>
                );
              })}
            </MapView>
          </View>
        );
```

Map Pin:

```
const MapPin = ({ price, icon }: Props) => (
  <View style={styles.bubbleContainer}>
    <View style={styles.bubbleContent}>
      <icon />
      <Text style={styles.bubblePrice}>{price}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.bubbleArrow} />
  </View>
);
```

My data is:

```
  const staticData = [
    {
      name: 'test station',
      type: 'ShellIcon',
      price: '15.00p',
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 52.56504897473243,
        longitude: -1.9835459043698045,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'test station',
      type: 'BpIcon',
      price: '10.00p',
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 52.564655445785036,
        longitude: -1.9895132194946084,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'test station',
      type: 'TexacoIcon',
      price: '12.00p',
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 52.56675992926686,
        longitude: -1.9925531724706291,
      },
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is the mapping:

```
import ShellIcon from '../../../assets/images/xxx.svg';
import BPIcon from '../../../assets/images/xxx.svg';
import TexacoIcon from '../../../assets/images/xx.svg';

const ALL_ICONS = { ShellIcon, BPIcon, TexacoIcon };

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView>
      {staticData.map((marker, i) => {
        const MarkerIcon = ALL_ICONS[marker.type];
        return (
          <Marker key={index} coordinate={item.coordinates} ref={markerRef}>
            <MapPin price={item.price} icon={MarkerIcon} />
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </MapView>
  </View>
);
```

You can't just use the `string` value for it to obtain the variable from the `import` (Do note that `marker.type` is type of `string` whereas what you expecting in `icon` is something constructable like a SVG icon Component)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you initializing `marker` in the map but you try to reach the value using `item`.

```
import ShellIcon from '../../../assets/images/xxx.svg';
import BPIcon from '../../../assets/images/xxx.svg';
import TexacoIcon from '../../../assets/images/xx.svg';

    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            ...
    
            <MapView
              ..>
              {staticData.map((marker, i) => {
                const MarkerIcon = marker.type;
    
                return (
                  <Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinates} ref={markerRef}>
                    <MapPin price={marker.price} icon={MarkerIcon} />
                  </Marker>
                );
              })}
            </MapView>
          </View>
        );
```

Also, move your icon to `staticData` like below:

```
const staticData = [
    {
      name: 'test station',
      type: <ShellIcon/>,
      price: '15.00p',
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 52.56504897473243,
        longitude: -1.9835459043698045,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'test station',
      type: <BpIcon/>,
      price: '10.00p',
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 52.564655445785036,
        longitude: -1.9895132194946084,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'test station',
      type: <TexacoIcon/>,
      price: '12.00p',
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 52.56675992926686,
        longitude: -1.9925531724706291,
      },
    },
  ];
```

And change `MapPin` too:

```
const MapPin = ({ price, icon }: Props) => (
  <View style={styles.bubbleContainer}>
    <View style={styles.bubbleContent}>
      {icon}
      <Text style={styles.bubblePrice}>{price}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.bubbleArrow} />
  </View>
);
```

If you do not want to do it like this you need to write switch case in order to pass MarkerIcon by using type from staticData.